# Oracle Database 11g and TFS (2010) integration

Tags: oracle

I am currently in a team of 4 database developers, working with Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition. We use quite a bit of SQL/PLSQL and create many scripts. My colleagues send all their work to a specific person before they can be deployed in a production environment.

Instead of bombarding a colleague like this, we'd like to use a version control tool (Team Foundation Server 2010 in our case), pretty much as a code repository, where our work can be saved on a regular basis.

Since noone -- including me -- has any experience with TFS, I'd like to ask:

- How can we best deploy TFS (or perhaps any other version control tool) in a development and test environment, as a way to manage our work? Any downsides/advantages, any specific points to take into consideration, any tips/pointers?

This is more of an *organisational* exercise, rather than a technical one. So my current focus is not the installation, etc. but to find the best way to utilize version control in a small team.

Thanks!

EDIT: Perhaps you can also answer the question by recommending several TFS-specific features that might be useful to (Oracle) DBAs and developers.

Comment: I admit that the question is a bit broad, but I could use a push in the right direction.

Comment: Is TFS already installed?

Comment: Yeah, along with MS Visual Studio 2010. 

I didn't do the installation myself though, because the IT Help Desk does installations remotely.

Answer (score 0):

If TFS is in the picture then I assume Visual Studio is there also and Oracle creates [development tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html) (VS) that will allow you to VS with TFS. With this, you could then create Oracle Database Project in VS and maintain SQL scripts.